# How can I fill <ul> using jQuery and list returned from JSON ActionResult?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, view

I can populate this in my View running a submit to Controller.

```
<h4>Stores In Area</h4>
<ul>
    @foreach (var account in Model)
    {

        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(account.UserName, "StoreAccountDetails", new { id = account.AccountID })
            @Html.Encode(account.Phone)
            @Html.Encode(account.Email)
            @Html.Encode(account.Radius)
            @Html.Encode(account.Distance)
            @Html.Encode(account.City)
            @Html.Encode(account.State)
          </li>

    }
</ul>
```

I am trying to keep from submitting and roundtripping the whole View:
I can use ajax to call JSON Action Result with test button click.
It brings back the correct number of rows, but I don't know how to populate
the "ul". I can empty the "ul" in the JSON response, which tells me the code runs, but not sure how to loop through the responsObject and script the "li" tags.

```
        function retrieveStores(thisLat, thisLng) {
            alert("inside retrieveStores, " + thisLat + ":::" + thisLng);  //THIS WORKS
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Stores/GetStores/",
                data: {lat: thisLat, lng: thisLng},
                type: 'POST',
                success: handleResultResponse,  //THIS WORKS
                error: function (xhr) { $('#lblNotice').text("there are no stores in this area . . . yet"); }
            });
        }

        //handles data back from ajax call for Stores
        function handleResultResponse(responseObject) {

            alert(responseObject); //THIS RETURNS 4 "object Object"s separated by commas
            alert("inside handleResultResponse ul empty is next"); //THIS WORKS
            $("ul").empty(); //THIS WORKS AND EMPTY'S THE ONLY UL (I will probably give it an id).

//BELOW HERE IS WHERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO LOOP THROUGH THE <ul> AND FILL IT WITH <li>'s.
///LOOP THROUGH responeObject BUILDING <il>s HERE////
        }
```

In the controller, here is the JSON ActionResult

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetStores(float lat, float lng)
{

//THIS BELOW RETURNS 4 ROWS
        var stores = _db.GetDistanceFromLatLongs2(lat, lng).ToList();

        var results = new JsonResult();


        if (stores.Any())
        {

            results = new JsonResult { Data = stores };
        }


        return results;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

***Option 1 :*** You can iterate the `JSON` and fill the respective elements of the table like :

```
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      var row= '<tr><td>' + val.your_property + '</td></tr>';
      $('#table').append(row);
    });
  });
```

---

***Option 2*** : You can use **`AngularJS`**; use `ng-repeat` for the rows like

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
  <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">
    {{key}}: {{val}}
  </td >
</tr >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleResultResponse(responseObject) {
    var _liHTML = "",
        _ul = $("ul"); //should provide id

    $.each(responseObject, function(index, value){
        _liHTML += "<li>" + value.property_name + "</li>";
    });

    _ul.html(_liHTML);
}
```

Comment: value.property_name returns "undefined". If I use JSON.stringify(value) inside the 2 "li"s I get the whole row I want, but it has field names, and quotes besides the values:
{"AccountID":2,"UserName":"User1","Phone":"503-358-5901","Email":"xxx@xxx.com","Radius":80,"Distance":1.7788856195409057,"City":null,"State":null,"Lat":45.52,"Long":-122.64}
{"AccountID":3,"UserName":"FredAckStare","Phone":"5039999999","Email":"www@sss.com","Radius":100,"Distance":1.9836792859217536,"City":null,"State":null,"Lat":45.51,"Long":-122.64}

Answer (score 0):

After trying both answers to my questions and futzing around I found the only way I could get my code to work as soon as possible was to script a table in the Controller's JSONResult and send it as a string and set the innerHtml of a Div with it.

In the Immediate window I was able to figure out the contents of the list() returned from my stored procedure. I was able to loop through and populate an html table.

I would attribute my success to the fact that I could set a break point and then question the list object I was sending back. I was able to get the row Count, and syntax for each field: stores[i].AccountID. . . .stores.Count and so on.

I couldn't figure this out for the JSON object that came back in the View's  response and I couldn't stop at runtime in the javacript code in the view either. I was able to use JSON.stringify(value) to get the whole row:
(I know the stuff is in there, I just can't see loopin inside of a loop inside a JSON jQuery block to mess with it.. . .If I could ever figure out the syntax.

Here is what stringify shows for my responseObject:

```
{"AccountID":2,"UserName":"User1","Phone":"503-358-5901","Email":"xxx@xxx.com","‌​Radius":80,"Distance":1.7788856195409057,"City":null,"State":null,"Lat":45.52,"Lo‌​ng":-122.64} {"AccountID":3,"UserName":"FredAckStare","Phone":"5039999999","Email":"www@sss.c‌​om","Radius":100,"Distance":1.9836792859217536,"City":null,"State":null,"Lat":45.‌​51,"Long":-122.64} – and so on.
```

I'm no stranger to HTML tables and tweaking them with "Edit" "Delete" columns, all possible now. Guess it is just plain scripting but I'm not planning on returning many rows and don't even think a JSON object is faster than a string.

But mainly, this answer is more of solution to my problem, which the question outlines even though someone out there could explain how to loop inside a loop to get 8-10 columns per row out of the JSON response/list returned. My guess is that someone that smart is busy at work and not reading my questions. lol

I don't want to upset the Overflow gods so please advise if this answer is not appropriate. And post an answer too if you want.

Here is my controller's code with the html string scripting:

```
public JsonResult GetStores(float lat, float lng)
{

    var stores = _db.GetDistanceFromLatLongs2(lat, lng).ToList();

    var results = new JsonResult();

    if (stores.Any())
    {
        string htmlString = "<table><thead><th>AccountID</th><th>UserName</th><th>Phone</th></thead>";
        var i = 0;
            while(i < stores.Count)
            {
                htmlString += "<tr>";
                htmlString += "<td>" + stores[i].AccountID + "</td>";
                htmlString += "<td>" + stores[i].UserName + "</td>";
                htmlString += "<td>" + stores[i].Phone + "</td>";
                htmlString += "</tr>";
                i++;
            }

        htmlString += "</table>";

        results = new JsonResult { Data = htmlString};
    }

    return results;
    }
}
```